# Backgroundworker not cancelling

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, backgroundworker

So I have a webpage scraper that uses backgroundworker to process each page. I also want to mention that I'm using MVVM light framework.

Inside my MainViewModel Constructor I am initializing the backgroundworker:

```
backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker()
        {
            WorkerReportsProgress = true,
            WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
        };
        backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
```

On the LoadCompleted event of a WebBrowser control I start the backgroundworker:

```
wb = sender; //sender is the webbrowser control
        if (!backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
        {
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

My next two methods are DoWork And StopWork:

```
private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent _resetEvent = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
    private object wb;

    void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker wk = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (wb != null)
        {
            FetchPage(wb);

            if (wk.CancellationPending)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Cancellation pending!");
            }

            _resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }

    private void StopWork(object sender)
    {
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        _resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

The fetchpage method will grab the sourcecode of the webbrowser control and start parsing it for content.

Inside of FetchPage I'm using BeginInvoke to update my UI thread:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
            () =>
            { ... }
```

My issue:
When I hit the Cancel button the StopWork method get's invoked, the cancel property on the backgroundWorker is set correctly to true, but the app just keeps going on. My if (wk.CancellationPending) is always false.

Any idea on what am I doing wrong here? I looked at tons of examples online and here on StackOverflow and they all state the same things that i already done.

Thanks.

EDIT:

After Ernos reply I tried passing the CancellationPending property to the FetchPage method and check for it in different locations, but it did not stop the processing.

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker wk = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (wb != null)
        {
            FetchPage(wb, wk.CancellationPending);

            _resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```

Inside of FetchPage I'm using BeginInvoke to update my UI thread:

```
private void FetchPage(object sender, bool stopAll)
{
     if (stopAll)
     {
         return;
     }
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(
            () =>
            { ... }
```

What I have tried and worked was:

```
private bool stopAllWork = false;

...

private void StopWork(object sender)
    {
        stopAllWork = true;
        backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
        _resetEvent.WaitOne();
    }
```

and then inside DoWork:

```
void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker wk = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        if (wb != null)
        {
            FetchPage(wb, stopAllWork);

            _resetEvent.Set();
        }
    }
```

Now, because of this implementation my concern is if there will be any rogue backgroundWorkers remaining?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to evaluate the `CancellationPending` inside the `FetchPage` method.

You are checking it AFTER the load of work.

Comment: Erno, thank you for your reply. The thing is that I tried it that way too, but CancellationPending is still false. For some reason the CancellationPending is never true. I think the backgroundworker ends before ever being evaluated. If I put a bool property stopAll at the class level and then I mark that as true, when it gets evaluated, the app will stop. How do I make sure I have no background thread remaining in limbo?

Comment: You could Check the status of the background workers by using the IsBusy property and wait for it or Cancel the worker.

Comment: Doooh! LoL! Thank you for your time Erno!

Comment: I just noticed you use IsBusy in your code :) No problem, glad to help out.

Answer (score 1):

Erno is correct. You are checking if it is cancelled after you have done all of the work. To keep things modular, you may consider not passing the background worker to FetchPage; rather pass a function that returns if you should cancel.

```
public void FetchPage(WebBrowser wb, Func<bool> cancelNow)
{
  ...
  if(cancelNow()) {
    return;
  }
  ...
}
```

You would call it like so

```
FetchPage(wb, () => wk.CancellationPending);
```

but you could put that function in another application that does not use a background worker and call it like so:

```
FetchPage(wb, () => false);
```

Note: make sure you are checking if you should cancel as the work is being completed. For example if most of the work happens in a loop, check inside the loop. If there are a series of steps, check between each step.

Comment: Thank you for you reply JDwyer, but as I also replied to Erno that approach did not work.